# Leave default shipping address blank in magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I am working on a magento site where the client is operating a business that sends ecards to other people. I need to find a way to keep the shipping address blank in onepage checkout, and then populate the fields from the users address book if they choose to do so with ajax, otherwise leaving the form blank because his particular product will never ship to the billing address. I have tried removing the values from the phtml, which broke the checkout process. I then tried removing the field values in accordion.js before they are sent back to the page, which also broke the checkout process, though both of these cleared the form correctly. This seems like it should be a pretty simple thing to accomplish, but I've been on this for several days now without any success. How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good extension from excellencemagentoblog here is the [link](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-shipping-method-step). I think it will work for you.